# Accessing Search Result

Tags: c#, winforms, search

I'm developing a winform application that will search for a string in the filenames of a specified source directory.. The problem is I need to access the file ..

Example: The search result is a .flv or .swf -- When the search is finished .. the result should be accessible.

This is what I have so far ..

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            txtOutput.Text = "";

            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\Sample"))
                if (Path.GetFileName(file).Contains(txtSearch.Text))
                    txtOutput.Text += txtOutput.Text + file + ", ";
        }
```

With this code I was able to search the file but it is not accessible .. also the output of the search came with the path of the file .. ( something like this c:\users\John\desktop\sample\Filename.swf ) I need a file name only, not the whole path..

I'm using a Multiline Textbox for the output, should I use something else? .. If you have a better suggestion please help me.

Comment: You are already using the Path.GetFileName(file) property. You should store it in a variable and use it to append to your textbox.

Comment: You say the file wasn't "accessible". What do you mean by that? All your code shows is that you're adding the filenames to the textbox. It sounds like it's doing exactly what you've programmed it to do.

Comment: What i mean is i need to use or run the search result .. i mean if it is a video file , when i clicked the result it should play the video.. something like that.. my output so far is a path, c:\users\John\desktop\sample\Filename.swf i cant access the flash video with this as my output..

Comment: You can start a new `Process` providing the fullFileName. This will open the default application (bound by the windows registry) to open the file. I.e. Some flash player for .swf files.

Comment: Im sorry to ask, but can you give a sample code? please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for files with certain extension, then use search pattern of `EnumerateFiles` or [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) methods. Also use [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get file name from file path:

```
var path = "C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\Sample";
txtOutput.Text = String.Join(", ", Directory.GetFiles(path, "*" + txtSearch.Text)
                                            .Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f));
```

Your `txtSearch.Text` suppose to have extension of searched files (i.e. `.swf` or `.flv`). Thus search pattern will be `*.swf` or `*.flv`.

So, if your search textbox has text `.swf` and there are two sfw files in your sample directory, then you will get output as `file1.swf, file2.swf`.

---

If you want to search any substring in file name:

```
var path = "C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\Sample";
txtOutput.Text = 
     String.Join(", ", Directory.GetFiles(path, "*" + txtSearch.Text + "*")
                                .Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f)));
```

And instead of multiline textbox, use listbox for displaying files:

```
listBox1.DataSource = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*" + txtSearch.Text + "*")
                               .Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f))
                               .ToList();
```

UPDATE: opening files

```
private void listBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fileName = listBox1.SelectedItem as string;
    if (fileName != null)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine("C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\Sample", fileName);
        Process.Start(path);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add this on my code please ? i cant seem to understand where to put the code.. sorry to ask..

Comment: @JurelJacinto which option you are trying first one or last one? And what you have in your search texbox?

Comment: @JurelJacinto then your search text box should contain `.swf` with dot. You can change search pattern to `"*." + txtSearch.Text` if you want to specify extension without dot. And verify that you have `swf` files in your sample directory.

Comment: by the way, is there anyway that i dont have to write the file extension on the textsearch?

Comment: and something that will search even just the part of name.. like if i search File .. Filename, Filebox, boxfile, file will be the result. .

Comment: @JurelJacinto yes, use second option - it will match any part of file name

Comment: THE SECOnd option's different from 1st is just ("*" +) .. but the method of searching is still the same .. it still needs .html and substrings wasnt showned.

Comment: @JurelJacinto sure method is same. Result is different. And, btw both use `Directory.GetFiles`. With second approach add "*" to beginning and end of searched text. Verified. Works just fine for me. And I don't uderstand what substrings you are talking about.

Comment: i get it, the last problem is how can i access this files? how can i play it if it is a video, something like this .. by the way thanks for helping me until now :)

Comment: @JurelJacinto Simplest way is using `Process.Start` see my last update

Comment: ive got an error, the "Process" does not exist in the current context .. what could be the problem ?

Comment: Thanks a Lot! :) the Next Problem is that when i search, the first one highlighted on the Listbox1 open the moment i click the serach button ..

Answer (score 1):

You were getting close, here are a few changes I would make:

Create a ListBox instead of a multi-line text box.  It allows you to handle a double-click even on an item that way.  For my example, the ListBox name is ListBox1.

Change your button1_Click method to this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // You can add your seach text right to the GetFiles command, this will only  return files that match. 
        // You can set the list of of items int he ListBod to the result of GetFiles instead of having to loop through as well.
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\John\Desktop\Sample", "*" + txtSearch.Text + "*"));
    }
```

Then handle ListBox1_DoubleClick:

```
    private void listBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This will run whatever file name the user double-clicked
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: I did what you say, but this doesnt show anything on ListBox1? do i need to use something ?

i mean "using System.Windows.Forms;" ..

Comment: You need to add a ListBox to your form.  In designer mode, drag a ListBox from the toolbox.

Comment: I mentioned that you need to add "*" around txtSearch.Text but I hadn't added it to the code.  I edited to code to reflect it.  If it's still not working please let me know what your search text is.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        txtOutput.Text = "";
        List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\Sample")){
            if (Path.GetFileName(file).Contains(txtSearch.Text)){
                txtOutput.Text += txtOutput.Text + file + ", ";
                fileNames.Add(file);
            }
        }

    }
```

so here you can use the files from the fileNames List.